# for which pairs of integers $(n,k), n>1$ we could have $\phi(n(n+1)(4n-1))=12 \phi(k^2)$?

Tags: number-theory, totient-function, square-numbers

I have tried to find such pairs of integers $(n,k)$ with $n >1$ for which $\phi(n(n+1)(4n-1))=12 \phi(k^2)$ with $\phi$ is the Euler totionnt function but i didn't get any pairs, In the same time I can't disprove that there is no pairs satisfying that ,it seems that we should prove in the first that $n(n+1)(4n-1)$ is a perfect square such that : $n(n+1)(4n-1)=(6k)^2$ but also no pair I find for $n >1$

Comment: Is there any context for this?  It looks very arbitrary. How far out have you searched?

Comment: Taking $n=2$ we get $\varphi(2\times 3\times 7)=12$ on the left, so taking $k=1$ works.

Comment: @zeraouliarafik why did you left out other possibilities for [$\varphi(x)=12$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=phi%28n%29%3D12), except $6^2$? I'd start with considering $n=5m+j,\,j=0,1,2,3,4$ because $\gcd(n+1,4n-1)=\gcd(n+1,5)$ and $\varphi$ is a multiplicative function.

Comment: What searching did you do?  taking $n=5$ we get $\phi(5\times 6\times 19)=4\times 2 \times 18=144$ so taking $k=6$ works.

Comment: There are many, many solutions to this equation ($17$ of them with $n < 100$). It does indeed look ``very arbitrary'' as a problem.

Comment: at least [$612$](https://tinyurl.com/math-3691734-p1) solutions below $10^6$ (for $n$ may be more, there needed for $k$ to be below $10^6$ too)

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment.

First of all, you should note that $\phi(k^2)=k \cdot\phi(k)$ because suppose $k$ has prime factors $p_1,p_2, \dots, p_n$, (regardless of their exponents)
$$\phi(k^2)=k^2\left(1-\frac{1}{p_1}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{p_2}\right)\dots\left(1-\frac{1}{p_n}\right)$$
while 
$$\phi(k)=k\left(1-\frac{1}{p_1}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{p_2}\right)\dots\left(1-\frac{1}{p_n}\right)$$
Now, by the euclidean algorithm,$\gcd(4n-1,n)=\gcd(n-1,n)=1$ and of course $\gcd(n,n+1)=1$

while $\gcd(4n-1,n+1)=\gcd(n-4,n+1)=\gcd(n-4,5)$, so we need to check the case when $n-4$ is coprime with $5$ and the other case, suppose it is coprime with $5$, then
$$\phi(n(n+1)(4n-1))=\phi(n)\cdot\phi(n+1)\cdot\phi(4n-1)=12k \cdot\phi(k)$$
If it is not, then
$$\phi(n) \cdot \phi((n+1)(4n-1))=12k\cdot \phi(k)$$
Then you may suppose different numbers to be prime and use the property $\phi(p)=p-1$, does that help?